# How can I truncate a solr string field to 10 characters?

Tags: solr, indexing

I have created the following string field for indexing.

```
<fieldType name="short_text_for_sort" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <!-- TODO: truncate to 10 characters-->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How can I limit this field to 10 characters?  Do I need to write my own filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option: PatternTokenizerFactory and regex the input into whatever form you need.

Second option: Use the copyfield command, setting the maxChars parameter to 10.

Third option: deal with this before your data makes it to solr.

The second option is probably the easiest, and lets you keep the original field value intact.

Comment: Hello Mike, Can you please give an example. I am a solr newbie. thanks.

Comment: Fourth option:  use

`<filter class="solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory" prefixLength="10" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use a word length filter

`<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="10" />`

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory

*edit I might be mistaken. I am not sure this will truncate the token (looks like it might just filter the tokens)

Comment: correct that will just filter out the values, it will not truncate them.  use `TruncateTokenFilterFactory` to truncate